# Creating Account in the AWS Organizations using AWS SDK for Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

Can you give a sample about this question? I've tried something about it but not have succeeded yet. How can I create an account for someone else on my master account?

```
    @Bean
        public AWSOrganizations createAwsAccount(){
            CreateAccountRequest createAccountRequest = new CreateAccountRequest();
            createAccountRequest.setAccountName("newAccount");
            createAccountRequest.setEmail("newAccount@yandex.com");
            createAccountRequest.setIamUserAccessToBilling("ALLOW");
            //createAccountRequest.setRoleName("");
            AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
            final AWSOrganizations awsOrganizations = AWSOrganizationsClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();
            awsOrganizations.createAccount(createAccountRequest);
            return awsOrganizations;
        }
```

I know, the code I wrote does not make any sense but I just wanted to try something. I'm waiting for your help about this subject.

```
ErrorMessage: You cannot add accounts to your organization while it is initializing. Try again later.
```

Comment: Is `awsOrganizations` ever initialized?

Comment: What is throwing the `NullPointerException` ... the call on `.createAccount()`? As @Tdorno suggests, if that is the case, please share also your code which initializes the client. In general (for AWS client instances) this is code like `AWSOrganizations orgs = new AWSOrganizationsClient.Builder().withFoo(foo).build();`

Comment: Hi @Tdorno, thank you for your quick reply. Can you give an example? In this example, I forgot to initialize but when I initialized it, nothing happened. Also, I didn't get any error.

Comment: @Jameson I've updated my codes above. Can you check? 
I am not getting any errors, but I can not create an account.

Comment: @Tdorno, I've updated my codes above. Can you check? 
I am not getting any errors, but I can not create an account.

Comment: @hsnclk the code above still doesn't really "make sense", per se. Taking a step back, let me say this. The best way I have found to program for the AWS APIs is to first get a working setup using a scripting language -- e.g., write a shell script with the AWS CLI. Everytime you do a create or update call, you should check status. For this API, that means `describe-create-account-status`. And for every request/result pair, you should always inspect the result. Most of the APIs will throw exceptions to represent 400/500 series errors. Organizations is new and the doco is still a bit light.

Comment: @Jameson sorry, I forgot to add this line `awsOrganizations.createAccount(createAccountRequest);` . But now I'm getting the error above.

Comment: I'm getting this same error with a newly created organization through the console, so I don't think it is an API issue.

Comment: Is resolving this just a matter of waiting a while?

Answer (score 1):

You probably resolved this already, but just in case anyone else finds this:

It seems to be an issue with AWS that is taking them forever to fix!

Look at [this thread in the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=772668).  It was opened on March and some (including me) are still having issues.  The API call is correct, you just have to either continue waiting (days? weeks?), contact support, or put a message on that topic.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In that discussion, I have already asked the same question but nobody has returned yet. It seems that there is a bug.

Comment: @hsnclk I finally created a new thread and after a couple days they created a case for me and they were able to resolve it.  I would recommend you to either create a new thread asking for that, or if you need it faster, pay for support and create a new case.

Comment: BTW, I believe they block that for new accounts. In an old account it was enabled instantly, in a new account I have to explain my use case instead. So it might help if you explain why you want to create new accounts. idk, just a suggestion.

Comment: I wanted to create a basic email service like MailChimp using Amazon services. My purpose was that when a user signed up for our system, the program would create an AWS account for themselves. But I couldn't succeed.

Comment: @hsnclk, from a quick look, it doesn't seem like a good approach anyway. But that's a discussion for another topic!